# Which of following subgroups of $G$ are normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For real numbers $a$ and $b$, define a mapping $g_{a,b}\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $g_{a,b}(x)=ax+b$.

Let $G = \{g_{a,b}\mid a,b \in R, a\neq0\}$.
Under composition of mappings this becomes a group. Which of following subgroups of $G$ are normal?

1. $H=\{g_{a,b}\mid a\neq0,a\in Q, b \in \mathbb R\}$
2. $H=\{g_{a,b}\mid b \in \mathbb R\}$
3. $H=\{g_{a,b}\mid b \in \mathbb Q\}$

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: How do i start?How do i check condition  $ghg^{-1}$

Comment: It may help if you notice that $G \cong \left\{ \pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & 1} : a,b \in \mathbb R, a\ne 0 \right\}$

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do this problem: You start by taking the first subgroup, $H_1$, and take an arbitrary $h_{a, b}$ inside that subgroup, take an arbitrary $g_{c, d} \in G$, and find the concrete expression for the composited transformation $g_{c, d}h_{a, b}g_{c, d}^{-1}$. You then need to decide whether this new element will always be an element if $H_1$, no matter what $a, b, c, d$ are (except that $a \in \Bbb Q$, since $h_{a, b} \in H_1$, and $a,c \neq 0$, of course).

If it is always an element of $H_1$, then $H_1$ is normal. You will need to present some kind of reasoning for why this must be true. If you're lucky, it will be evident just from the concrete expression of $g_{c, d}h_{a, b}g_{c, d}^{-1}$. If there is even one single choice of $a, b, c, d$ (still with the restriction to $a$ and $c$) that makes $g_{c, d}h_{a, b}g_{c, d}^{-1} \notin H_1$, then $H_1$ is not normal. Putting forth such $a, b, c, d$ is enough proof for that.

Then you do the same thing for $H_2$ and $H_3$.

Answer (score 1):

For the subgroup $H=\{g_{a,b}\:|\:a\neq 0,\:a\in\mathbb{Q},\:b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ to be normal, we would need that
\begin{equation}
g^{-1}hg\in H
\end{equation}
for every $g\in G$.

So let's do this:
\begin{equation}
q(x)=\frac{(x-b)}{a}\circ (cx+d)\circ (a'x+b')\qquad\qquad a,a',b,b',d\in\mathbb{R}\qquad c\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}
We need to check if $q(x)\in H$. Solving we get
\begin{equation}
q(x)=a'\Big(c\cdot \frac{(x-b)}{a}+d\Big)+b'= \frac{a'c}{a}x+\text{real term}.
\end{equation}
Well, if $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $a,a'\in\mathbb{R}$, is it true that $\frac{a'c}{a}\in\mathbb{Q}$? You can do something similar for the other ones.

Btw I forgot to mention that the denominators on fractions and $a,a'$ are $\neq 0$ but this is obvious.

Also, I think that you should first do some computations with composition of these "affine functions" to get some grasp on what compositions look like and what inverses look like (which I implictly used in the answer above).